# Get substring after a word and before an filename extension

Tags: javascript

I have a URL in the following format:

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/xyzzz/image/upload/v1673615977/dealetePosts/hokhqmcmmkveqhxtr0nb.jpg
```

How to extract `hokhqmcmmkveqhxtr0nb` from this?
So extract contents between `dealetePosts` and `.jpg`

String position, followed by substring would work but is there an easier way?

This is what I have so far and works but is this the best way?

```
const publicID = dealPic.substring(
  dealPic.indexOf("dealetePosts/") + 13, 
  dealPic.lastIndexOf(".jpg")
);
```

Comment: It's ok, but this is not scalable.

Comment: You could look into using the `URL()` class to do some of the heavy lifting for you and to offer a lot more flexibility

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like a split and pop method to slash "/"  & "." characters. Thats if you are always expecting the same type of url.

```
let url = "https://res.cloudinary.com/xyzzz/image/upload/v1673615977/dealetePosts/hokhqmcmmkveqhxtr0nb.jpg";
let key = url.split("/").pop().split(".")[0];
console.log(key);
```

or you can replace and write some regex.

```
let extension = url.replace(/^.*\./, "")
console.log(extension);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the substring function and a regex to remove any extension (jpg, png, etc) and it'works even if dealetePosts changed to anyother name

```
const test = "https://res.cloudinary.com/xyzzz/image/upload/v1673615977/dealetePosts/hokhqmcmmkveqhxtr0nb.jpg"


function substr(str = ""){
  
  const lastIndexSlash = str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1
  
  
  return str.substring(lastIndexSlash, str.length).replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
}


console.log(substr(test))
```

Comment: This seems more flexible for other users and for multiple scenarios such as different kind of image extensions. Good job !!

Answer (score 0):

Another option that could be considered easier to read and understand is using regular expressions to match the text you want to extract. The following code will match the text between "dealetePosts/" and ".jpg" and return it as the first captured group:

```
const publicID = dealPic.match(/dealetePosts\/(.*)\.jpg/)[1];
```